# Task Scheduler / Event Viewer - Specifically with Logitech Lightspeed Activity

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, event-viewer, logitech-headset

I'm trying to automate a task. When I want to automate the audio toggle trigger by the headset being turned on or off.
When turned on, I'd like to switch audio input/output to the headset.
When turned off, I'd like to switch back to the other devices.

I figured Task Scheduler would be the way to go. I may have overthought it and there may be an easier solution. Just going for convenience. Could just go back to a hotkey audio toggle.

I'm trying to narrow down the events for any Logitech device that utilizes a Lightspeed connection. The wireless adapter is plugged in at all times. The device has a on/off toggle or switch.
In the Logitech Hub App, the devices will show when they are connected (active) or not connected (grayed out).

I've searched Event Viewer manually and searched everywhere online for any leads. Searched for an event identifier for any activity to narrow down any activity to narrow down connected and disconnected events.

I've tried to search for the headset, speakers, microphone, wireless adapter and USB port/hub. I did not see anything that stuck out I could try to enable to find this.
I could only find events of driver updates for the device.

I would have tried what triggers the hardware connection sound, but it's the wireless received that is always connected. So when the headset is powered on, it's not recognized as a new device.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The title is unclear to me: How does "ISO" apply to this question?

Comment: This one isn't help with an image. It's the abbreviation for "in search of". Sorry about that.